# Maven - Create WAR with including JAR from dependent project

Tags: maven, jar, project, war, pom.xml

The Project Structure as below

- ProjectJAR1.jar and ProjectJAR2.jar should be created
- Both the jars should be copied to ProjectWAR.war/WEB-INF/lib

is this possible with maven? any sample code

```
|Parent
├──pom.xml
|
├───────ProjectJAR1
|       ├─pom.xml
|       ├─src
|
├───────ProjectJAR2
|       ├─pom.xml
|       ├─src
|
├───────ProjectWAR1
|       ├─pom.xml
|       ├─src
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. You should look at maven-war-plugin [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

In *ProjectWAR1* webapp module, you can use `mvn clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true install` to build the web project, at the same time it can generate **WAR** in *ProjectWAR1/target* directory.

Comment: I don't see any reason to do a `clean` first, nor to skip all tests, nor to copy the artifacts in the local repository first. `mvn package` is sufficient to get the same result.